# "gerund + and/while + gerund + is"; which is more common, 'and' or 'while'?

Tags: gerunds, compound-nouns, compound-subjects

> Drinking and driving is dangerous.[[1]](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=9M6Gza8KhA1g.html)
>
> Texting and driving is dangerous.[[2]](https://www.debate.org/opinions/should-texting-and-driving-be-a-primary-offense)
>
> Yes, texting while driving is criminal.[[2]](https://www.debate.org/opinions/should-texting-and-driving-be-a-primary-offense)

Both styles are common, are both grammatical too? And which is more common and preferred?

Comment: Personally, I think, both are grammatical; 'while' is less common. And as google-ngram has got no entries for 'drinking while driving is' but got many for 'drinking and driving is' link: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drinking+and+driving+is%2Cdrinking+while+driving+is&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdrinking%20and%20driving%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20driving%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDrinking%20and%20driving%20is%3B%2Cc0

Comment: “I know eating and drinking while driving is dangerous, but I see many drivers doing it.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, personally, find records of only the "Drinking and driving" type of structures on [N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drinking%20and%20*%20is%2Cdrinking%20while%20*%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdrinking%20and%20%2A%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20cooking%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20driving%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20smoking%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20bathing%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20drunkenness%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20eating%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20alcoholism%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20washing%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrinking%20and%20who%20is%3B%2Cc0).

Regardless of which is common, both are grammatically sound;

- (The act of) Drinking and driving is dangerous.
- (The act of) Texting and driving is dangerous.
- Yes, (the act of) texting (while you're) driving is criminal.

"Drinking and driving" would take singular verb when it means or refers to "Drinking" while "driving", otherwise a plural verb would be used. For example;

- Drinking and driving are two different things.
- Both drinking and gambling are socio-economic evils.